# How to call node and npm in my os?

Tags: debian, node.js

I want to install npm and node.

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm nodejs
```

It encounter some warning:

```
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Now try hard to fix the dependencies of broken packages with argument `-f`.

```
sudo aptitude -f install  npm  nodejs
```

No node command can called:

```
node -v
bash: node: command not found
npm -v
bash: npm: command not found
```

Try to find the `node`'s location.

```
sudo find /  -name  'node'
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64/include/config/have/memblock/node
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64/include/config/use/percpu/numa/node
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64/include/config/have/memblock/node
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64/include/config/use/percpu/numa/node
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-12-amd64/include/config/have/memblock/node
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-12-amd64/include/config/use/percpu/numa/node
/sys/devices/system/node
/sys/bus/node
/proc/irq/0/node
/proc/irq/1/node
/proc/irq/2/node
/proc/irq/3/node
/proc/irq/4/node
/proc/irq/5/node
/proc/irq/6/node
/proc/irq/7/node
/proc/irq/8/node
/proc/irq/9/node
/proc/irq/10/node
/proc/irq/11/node
/proc/irq/12/node
/proc/irq/13/node
/proc/irq/14/node
/proc/irq/15/node
/proc/irq/18/node
/proc/irq/20/node
/proc/irq/23/node
/proc/irq/24/node
/proc/irq/25/node
/proc/irq/26/node
/proc/irq/27/node
/proc/irq/28/node
/proc/irq/29/node
```

Search `npm`:

```
sudo find  /  -name  'npm'
#nothing searched
```

How to call node and npm in my os?

Thank to @Freddy,it located in `/usr/bin/nodejs`.

```
nodejs -v
v4.8.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your existing kernel version you're probably running Debian stretch and the node binary
should be installed to `/usr/bin/nodejs` (see the [filelist](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/nodejs/filelist)).

In newer Debian releases the binary is installed to `/usr/bin/node` and an additional symlink `/usr/bin/nodejs` points to the `node` binary.

Comment: /usr/bin/nodejs  -v
v4.8.2

Comment: And how to call `npm` then?

Comment: If you have the backports version installed, it's `/usr/bin/npm`, so `npm` should work.